# How to click link on web element corresponding to some text field in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to click on a link of numbers, of some corresponding value; but I am not able to select the exact hyperlink as the value. In the below code, the 2 `Endpoint Call` is not able to click on that number, selecting the `Endpoint Ping` too in the same Xpath.

Comment: Please consider adding some clear detail to your question, I'm not sure I understand it.  You wish to click the link after 'Endpoint Ping' which will be the number 2 in this case?  Will the number always be 2 or is the only known that it appears after Endpoint Ping?

Comment: What does "not able to" mean? Why aren't you able to? What have you tried, and what is the result of what you've tried? Did it pick the wrong element? Did it throw an error? If so, what error?

Comment: @Shicky this number 2 is dynamic value which is actually gives the count of Endpoint Ping.Yes I want to click number 2 which is link.

Comment: @Bryan I have tried couple of ways but its not able to select the desired ("2") link correspondence to Endpoint Ping.

Comment: @Bryan I have tried couple of ways but its not able to select the desired ("2") link correspondence to Endpoint Ping..I have tried this  //span[contains(text(),'Confirm Registration')]/../following::*/a     which selects all the link next to Endpoint Ping value.But I want to select only one link which is correspondence to Endpoint Ping.

Answer (score 0):

Does the following work?  If not, please provide more information on why it failed etc.

```
Wait Until Keyword Succeeds    4 sec   1 sec    Click Element    xpath=//td[@class="WG7B-Row ctl00PageBodyCommandGrid-Brd"]/a
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below, it will not fail

```
(//span[text()='Endpoint Ping']/following::a)[1]
```

Comment: Thank you. Can you please accept the answer? Have a great time!

Answer (score 0):

Another way you can use this code.

```
 *** Variable ***
    ${profile}          https://web.facebook.com/xxx
 *** Keywords ***
    Click Profile
    [Arguments]        ${xpath}
    Click Element      ${xpath}
 *** Test Cases ***
    Go To           ${profile}
```

Hope to help.